# Does dark energy increase eccentricity in orbits of galaxies?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, expansion, dark-energy, galaxy-cluster

I came across this [thesis dissertation](https://louis.uah.edu/uah-dissertations/31/) which indicates that if a pair of orbiting galaxies are sufficiently far apart (with a sufficiently large orbital radius) then their orbits would change from circular to eccentric orbits by the "anti-gravity" effects of Dark Energy.

If that would happen, then, could these galaxies suffer tidal effects (such as [tidal heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_heating)) due to the increasingly eccentricity of the orbits?

Would they eventually be unbounded forever or could there be some possibility where the tidal effects would re-circularize the orbit (at least for some part) before the orbit becomes extremely eccentric and they become unbound?